# Create Folder on desktop using user input in Batch File

Tags: batch-file, directory

I am trying to make a batch file that will make a folder on the desktop from user input. Here is my code:

```
echo What do you want the folder to be called?
SET /p folderName=
md C:\Users\%username%\desktop\%folderName%
```

However, whenever I try this, It gives me an error saying:

```
A subdirectory or file C:\Users\Razi\desktop\ already exists.
```

It doesn't seem to be noticing the `%folderName%` at the end. 
Can somebody tell me what's wrong with my code and give an alternative? Thank you!

Comment: Your batch file works well for me. I get the same result as you only if I press Enter without specifying a subfolder name.

Comment: It works for me. Try echoing the variable and placing a pause to see what its' value is. Also if you don't type anything it will have that error.

Comment: Just curious: what was there to fix?

Comment: instead of `C:\Users\%username%` you should use `%userprofile%` (`c:\users\` is the default, but you can't rely on it)

Comment: Oviously, `%folderName%` appears to be empty, as you can see in the error message which includes the path argument the `md` command receives; so `md` tries to create the already existing directory `Desktop`; if the error appears even when you enter a valid directory name, I am pretty sure that the code fragment is part of a block in between parentheses, in which case you need to enable and apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html); otherwise you read the `folderName` value present *before* the entire block is executed...

Comment: @aschipfl Yes, that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Oviously, `%folderName%` appears to be empty, as you can see in the error message which includes the path argument the `md` command receives. So `md` tries to create the already existing directory `Desktop`.

If the error appears even when you enter a valid directory name, I am pretty sure that the code fragment is part of a block in between parentheses, in which case you need to enable and apply [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Otherwise you read the `folderName` value present before the entire block is executed.

For instance, the following block is seen as a single command line by the command interpreter; `%folderName%` is expanded (replaced by its value) as soon as the whole line/block is parsed:

```
(
    echo What do you want the folder to be called?
    set /P folderName=
    md "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\%folderName%"
)
```

In the following, delayed expansion is enabled (by `setlocal`); to actually use it, the `%` expansion has been changed to `!`; so `!folderName!` is expanded (read) later, as soon as it is executed:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
rem ...
(
    echo What do you want the folder to be called?
    set /P folderName=
    md "%USERPROFILE%\desktop\!folderName!"
)
rem ...
endlocal
```

Note that the changed value of `folderName` is no longer available as soon as `endlocal` has been executed, or the batch file terminates (where an implicit `endlocal` happens).

In addition to the above, I put quotation marks around the path at the `md` command to avoid trouble with white-spaces or special characters, and I changed `C:\Users\%USERNAME%` to `%USERPROFILE%` as recommended in [Stephan's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35996103/create-folder-on-desktop-using-user-input-in-batch-file#comment59646203_35996103).